# Creating .exe file with pyinstaller and Matlab engine

Tags: d3.js, python-3.x, matlab, pyinstaller, matlab-engine

I have made an application using `pyqt` . when running from an IDE the .py files work good. However when running the .exe file using:

```
pyinstaller --name="Myapp" --windowed --onefile main.py
```

I get a .exe file. When I try to run it it says

```
Failed to execure script main
```

I tried again but this time with :

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

It did generated a folder named `main` in `dist`. I ran `main.exe` in command line and I get :

```
ImportError: No module named 'mlarray'
```

I went to the `matlab` library for python that I had installed in `\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\matlab` and changed `mlarray.py` as following:
from

```
from _internal.mlarray_sequence import _MLArrayMetaClass
```

To:

```
from matlab._internal.mlarray_sequence import _MLArrayMetaClass
```

I even changed `__init__.py`:
from:

```
from mlarray import double, single, uint8, int8, uint16, \
    int16, uint32, int32, uint64, int64, logical
from mlexceptions import ShapeError as ShapeError
from mlexceptions import SizeError as SizeError
```

to:

```
from matlab.mlarray import double, single, uint8, int8, uint16, \
    int16, uint32, int32, uint64, int64, logical
from matlab.mlexceptions import ShapeError as ShapeError
from matlab.mlexceptions import SizeError as SizeError
```

Finally I changed `Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\matlab\_internal\mlarray_sequence.py`
from:

```
from _internal.mlarray_utils import _get_strides, _get_size, \
    _normalize_size, _get_mlsize, _reshape
```

to:

```
from matlab._internal.mlarray_utils import _get_strides, _get_size, \
    _normalize_size, _get_mlsize, _reshape
```

Saved all the work and try to do pyinstaller again.

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

and this time I get following error:

```
  File "site-packages\matlab\engine\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
OSError: Please reinstall MATLAB Engine for Python or contact MathWorks Technical Support for assistance: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\pmafgx_das\\das2\\main\\ReleaserQt\\dist\\main\\matlab\\engine\\_arch.txt'
[2028] Failed to execute script main
```

It is getting very frustrating and I don't know what to do more. Please if you have an insights I would appritiate if you could help me.

Answer (score 5):

First of all remove the changes to `matlab`.

Then create a directory structure - and the `hook-matlab.py` file - like the following tree:

```
- script_to_compile.py  # This is the python file you run pyinstaller on
- hooks  # DIR
  - hook-matlab.py
```

And inside of `hook-matlab.py`:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('matlab')
```

Then build with the extra option `--additional-hooks-dir=hooks`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for response. The additional options in build. Do you mean that I should change the spec file? In case where?

Comment: @Payam30 compile with `pyinstaller myscript.py --additional-hook-dir=hooks --other-options`.

Comment: @Legorooj, thanks for this response, fixed my case! cheers